# Lucene Autocomplete in JSON data

Tags: java, neo4j, lucene

I am trying to build a search engine using Neo4j as backend & Java web application as frontend. Using Neo4j Java API, the data extracted is in JSON format. Any idea how to query the JSON data using Lucene for providing autocomplete suggestions to the user ???

Answer (score 0):

[Suggest lucene](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24968697/how-to-implements-auto-suggest-using-lucenes-new-analyzinginfixsuggester-api)

Check this thread I used this to create my autocomplete and richfaces for display this

Comment: Good suggestion. But JSON extraction is not mentioned in that post

Answer (score 0):

For autocomplete there's a very helpful new feature in 2.3:

```
MATCH (n:Person)
WHERE n.name starts with 'Jo'
RETURN n
```

returns person nodes like 'John' and 'Joanne' based on a index search.

Of course the index has be created using

```
CREATE INDEX ON :Person(name)
```

Comment: Its not just name, i have to provide autocomplete suggestions on multiple nodes, so i thought of extracting them in JSON format through JAVA API and then use Lucene for autocomplete